# Override default text label for any external packages in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-apps, django-modeladmin

It's the classic way to describe Modules in Django Admin, and it works great!

at bookshelf/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class BOOKConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'bookshelf'
    verbose_name = "Your Book"
```

at `bookshelf/__init__.py`:

```
default_app_config = 'bookshelf.apps.BOOKConfig'
```

BUT when you want to override titles of external modules (e.g. like packages from https://djangopackages.org/), what's the right way to override the default name at this sections and the items inside that?

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#configuring-applications), new applications should avoid default_app_config.

Instead of adding `default_app_config` to the app's `__init__.py`, just use the dotted path to the app config in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'bookshelf.apps.BOOKConfig'
    ...
]
```

For a third-party app you can do the same thing. Create an `apps.py` somewhere in your project (e.g alongside `myproject/settings.py`), and create an app config.

```
from third_party_app..apps import ThirdPartyConfig

class MyThirdPartyConfig(ThirdPartyConfig):
    verbose_name = "Customized app name"
```

If the app doesn't have an App Config class, then subclass `AppConfig` and make sure you set `name`.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class MyThirdPartyConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'third_party_app'
    verbose_name = "Customized app name"
```

Then use the path to your app config class in `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of the app name/default app config.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myproject.apps.MyThirdPartyConfig,
    ...
]
```

See the [for application users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#for-application-users) section of the docs for another example.

Comment: **It's works perfectly! Fantastic! Thank you so much Alasdair.**

One more thing(if anyone will try this too) at the bellow list we need to **remove origial app name to detriment of the new config** even perhaps add variable name to the new config like Alasdair said :D Greattttttt.

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'bookshelf.apps.BOOKConfig'
    ...
]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a model like this:

```
class Stuff(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'The stuff'
        verbose_name_plural = u'The bunch of stuff'
```

You have verbose_name, however you want to customise app_label too for different display in admin. Unfortunatelly having some arbitrary string (with spaces) doesn't work and it's not for display anyway.

Turns out that the admin uses app_label. title () for display so we can make a little hack: str subclass with overriden title method:

```
class string_with_title(str):
    def __new__(cls, value, title):
        instance = str.__new__(cls, value)
        instance._title = title
        return instance

    def title(self):
        return self._title

    __copy__ = lambda self: self
    __deepcopy__ = lambda self, memodict: self
```

Now we can have the model like this:

```
class Stuff(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = string_with_title("stuffapp", "The stuff box")
        # 'stuffapp' is the name of the django app
        verbose_name = 'The stuff'
        verbose_name_plural = 'The bunch of stuff'
```

Original Ionel's post https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2011/06/24/custom-app-names-in-the-django-admin/

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this while looking for a way to rename external Django installed apps / packages in my Django admin interface. I'm using Django 3.2.16. And the below is how I get it done.

In any of the apps.py of an included app using the external installed app, import the package apps.

```
from <package-name>.apps import <package-name>Config
```

Then, extend the verbose_name property.

```
<package-name>Config.verbose_name = '<custom-name-here>'
```

Hope this helps anyone coming over stumbling upon this question!